# Visualizing Audio while recording in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I`m trying to make an windows phone 8 app which simply allow you to click a button which result in start recording and showing any visualization that indicate that its recording something like a bar or a vu meter , I managed to make the recording part, now i dont know what type of projects i should use to support making such visualization.

does Windows phone 8 apps support using XNA to draw in a box inside a xaml file ?

what is the tag i can use to draw inside using XNA code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're targeting WP8 you can't use the hybrid SL/XNA model. That said, you can certainly use a Hybrid solution that draws using DirectX. You can find general information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207012%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and a sample [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Direct3D-with-XAML-Marble-1d51a37b) (note that it uses `DrawingSurfaceBackgroundGrid`, you probably want `DrawingSurface`).